# expressing $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^k a_k a_m t^{m+k}$ as power series of $t$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n t^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I change the following type (left one) of series into the one like right one? 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^k a_k a_m t^{m+k} \to \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n $$
or $a_{k,m}$ could be the coefficient of mixed type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the left side for a few terms, we see that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^ka_ka_mt^{m+k}=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}n\ge 0\\i+j=n\\ i\ge j\ge 0\end{array}}a_ia_jt^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{j=[(n+1)/2]}^n a_j a_{n-j} )t^n$$